# Posting HTML Form Values Over HTTPS

Tags: https, asp.net, forms, http-post

I have a website that is currently using https for secure login and transactions. You can't navigate to the to the main site unless you login.

I have had a request from a partner who have asked if they can seamlessly navigate to our site from their own web application, without logging in. There site is also using https.

I've set up a "PartnerLoginPage.aspx" page, and allowed them to POST html form values into this page (they have the correct user login details). I then authenticate them based on the posted values and redirect them to the main site. They don't need to login then, I've already authenticated them and it works perfectly.

My biggest concern is that this is not a secure way of authenticating the user. If you POST html form values into a https page is the data still encrypted? Just out of interest, if their site was not an http site (it is) would the data still be encrypted?

eg THEIR HTTPS-> FORM POST VALUES -> OUR HTTPS -> ARE FORM POST VALUES DATA ENCRYTPED?

and

THEIR HTTP (note: no 's') ->FORM POST VALUES -> OUR HTTPS -> ARE FORM POST VALUES ENCRTYPED?

Thanks for any help,

Stuart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all keys are valid, of course...

If the request is made an https page, then the request is encrypted (meaning the POST values, which are sent via the request, are encrypted, regardless of destination).

If the request is made from a non https page to an https page, the request is not encrypted, but the response would be, so the post variables are NOT encrypted (but the value returned would be).

HTTPS essentially sets up whether the server/page that is talking is using encryption or not, so http -> https = non-encrypted request, encrypted response, https -> http = encrypted-request, non-encrypted response.

Of course, there are levels of security that can be set at the script level, but I don't think your answer is worried about that.

### Quick Post Script

Why don't you give the partner sites a service account like "username :partners, pw: sheswithme" or some such? You could use cURL to set up the cookie and pass the server variables and have them point their form to a script that makes the request instead of having their users having semi-direct access to your script.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply Anthony. I've have a look cURL as I'm not too familiar with that.

Comment: cURL is a way to send http requests on the server side, really handy. I'm fairly sure you can use it with ASPX and .NET, but if not, look for an equivalent by searching for "server side http client".